# Should we add the thing about off-site libraries to the help page?

Tags: discussion

One of the most-used close reasons here is

> Questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" are discussion-oriented

But this is not clearly stated on the Help page. The help page says not to ask subjective questions. I just had a comment exchange with someone who didn't read the Help, and posted this kind of question. I said to read the help. He came back and said his question wasn't subjective. So I said it was clearly stated in the help that "which technology to use" questions are off-topic.

Then I looked, and it isn't clearly stated. Maybe it should be.

Comment: The [help page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does seem to mention all those topics in the close reason. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I was looking at "What can I not ask here" and expected to see those there. Just strange organization then. :)

Answer (score 5):

The information pertaining to what is and isn't on-topic is in the [`help/on-topic`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) link. The [main help page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) pointed to by the `[help]` quicklink and the close reason doesn't explicitly list them, but does contain a link to the "on topic" sub-page.

We can't edit the content of the main page, so all the information we want is already posted where we can put it. Beyond that, it's up to users to actually read the page and its links instead of skimming over it.