# How can I help improve the site?

Tags: discussion

I like this site and this community, and I have some time to spare.

What are the things that I can do to help improve the site?

Comment: You can try to convince the community about what is on-topic on this site. See: https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/should-we-add-the-thing-about-off-site-libraries-to-the-help-page?rq=1

Answer (score 14):

There is a bunch of things that can always be done:

- Answer [unanswered questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/unanswered).
- If your rep allows it, you can help [review posts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review).
- Participate in the on going development of the site by contributing questions, answers & votes to [meta](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

If that's not enough, here is a list of things that can be done as part of housekeeping:

- Fix the posts that have a high potential of [link rot](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2721).
- With the same philosophy, we should review the usage of links such as [bit.ly](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Abit.ly). While these are nice for short URLs, the target of these links can be changed, redirecting users to inappropriate sites after some time.
- Clean up the [software-engineering](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/should-we-alias-programming-to-programming-theory-or-software-engineering-o) tag.
- Improve posts by using [\$\LaTeX\$/MathJax](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mathjax-latex-in-posts-has-been-added-lets-make-some-math).
- Identify collections of questions that should be closed as duplicates, or for which a ["canonical question"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/flood-the-site-with-softball-questions) can be authored and used as a duplicate target (see [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/canonical-question-for-picking-a-random-element-from-a-set-with-weighted-probabi) for a recent example of this process in action).

---

This list should be updated when new stuff comes up :)

Comment: Regarding links to dead sites, can't it a) be detected automatically (or at least flagged automatically) and b) relink to Internet Archive (wayback machine) automatically? (automatically = from code)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no automatic way to do that. Based on my recent venturing in replacing links to gpwiki, there is no way to know _if_ there is an archive on web.archive.org, nor _which version_ is the right one, as there may be many and not all of them are "legit". Someone on [SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them) has made a post about this.